# how to kill msiexec.exe in wix?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have a wix application running.and when i am trying to uninstall it,it should prompt for close the application.I would like to kill the msiexec.exe after it prompts.Right now it prompts to close but as soon as i close the dialog box it shows there is some problem in the script and later Fatal error during installation comes.Please help me...

```
<CustomAction Id="Show" Script="vbscript">

<![CDATA[

set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")

If Process.Name = "CAS.exe" or Process.Name = "CMSS.exe"

then

msgbox "CAS  is running...Please close it before uninstalling"

 WScript.quit

End If

next

]]>

    </CustomAction>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action="Show" After="FindRelatedProducts">REMOVE</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and press the "code" button above the edit window.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand: why do you need to kill msiexec.exe? It is what actually running your installation!

Comment: If your installation is crashing, the fix is not to kill msiexec before the crash - the fix is to fix your installation script.

Comment: If you will kill msiexec then your installer will end as msiexec is used to execute an msi

Answer (score 0):

You can create an msi log file to determine which specific custom action failed during installation.

I would recommend not using

```
WScript.Quit
```

Instead, use

```
Exit For
```

for example.

If CMSS.exe and CAS.exe are not running, then set an msi property and then in your wxs file, specify a condition that checks the value of that property to determine if the next dialog should be displayed for example.